# How to move a folder to another path and to move back to same tree merging its contents on Unix?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, automation, file-management

On my Android phone, I have:

- A cron job to move files at 1:59am from /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media to /sdcard/wppmediabkp folder before WhatsApp backup at 2:00am:

`mv -f /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media /sdcard/wppmediabkp`

- A cron job to move files at 2:30am back (from /sdcard/wppmediabkp to /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media):

`mv -f /sdcard/wppmediabkp /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media`

- The "cron jobs" are tasks on "Tasks!" app (scheduling them with `00 59 1 ? * *` and `00 30 2 ? * *`). The commands are tested in Termux app also.

Aim:

- To exclude Media folder from backup, but to also restore image "link" to chats (to do not download again).

On restoration of wppmediabkp folder to /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media:

1. Sometimes it works well (it creates the /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media with all its contents). It happens when /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media folder does not exist. For me, it is the expected behavior.
2. Sometimes it creates a subfolder (/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/wppmediabkp). It happens when /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media folder exists. For me, it is the issue - I would like to restore original folder tree, merging its contents.

I think it was reduced to a Unix issue, because I can use all Unix basic commands.

How to solve it (to get Media folder back merging its contents) using `mv` command?

Comment: With `mv` (and `cp`), when the target is a directory, the last element of each source path is copied into the target directory, so the restore command command should be `mv -f /sdcard/wppmediabkp/Media /sdcard/WhatsApp/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is not to move directories. Let them exist all the time, move their *content* back and forth:

```
mv -f /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/* /sdcard/wppmediabkp/
# and later
mv -f /sdcard/wppmediabkp/* /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/
```

Notes:

- `*` will not match hidden files/directories;
- with too many objects you may hit "argument list too long" error.

In case any of this is an issue, the solution should use something like `find … -exec mv …`. Either way move what is inside the directory, not the directory itself.

Comment: Excellent! Although Schedule! app does not work well, Termux shows that they are correct for desired backup operation.